# Drawing a directed graph using a link matrix with networkx

Tags: python, matrix, graph, networkx, pagerank

I am working on pagerank for a school project, and i have a matrix where the row "i" represent the links from the site j (line) to the site i. (If it is still unclear i'll explain more).

The current part is:

```
Z=[[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],    [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]]
A=np.matrix(Z)
G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(A,create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())
pos=nx.circular_layout(G)
labels={}
for i in range (N):
    labels[i]=i+1
nx.draw_circular(G)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,labels,font_size=15)
```

The problem i have is that the labels are not where they are supposed to be, it seems that networkx is just placing them clockwise...

Also, how could i *easily* direct the graph, so that a link from j to i won't be from i to j?

Thanks!

Comment: The plot generated by the code looks correct to me. What result did you want?

Comment: The problem is that the labels on the graph aren't placed right i think, or maybe it is because the graph isn't directed.... But the labels aren't placed according to the matrix i think

Comment: Can you edit your code so that I can copy and paste it directly in so I"m sure I'm running the same thing as you?

Answer (score 5):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

Z = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.array(Z), create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw_circular(G)
labels = {i : i + 1 for i in G.nodes()}
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels, font_size=15)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

This result appears correct to me. Notice, for example, that the node labeled `1` has directed edges pointing to `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` and `7`. This corresponds to the ones on the first row in the array, `Z[0]`:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

since the first row corresponds to node 1, and the ones in this row occur in the columns corresponding to nodes `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` and `7`.

Comment: Oh thanks, i see the problem, i should transpose the matrix, because the first row in the array should be the links *pointing* to 1 and not from 1.